# Are balances of all accounts in memory or disk (storage)?

Tags: storage, memory

I simulated two contracts that sending balance to another and simply setting value of a variable(`var a = 5;`). In contrast my expectation, `{var a = 5;}` contract consumed more gas than the other.
 In my understanding, balance of accounts are stored in another place(i guess in memory), but general state(such as var a) are stored in disk(storage). Is it right? Or the other factor affected this results?

Answer (score 3):

Both account balances and contract storage are stored on disk in the state database.

Sending ether costs at least `21k` gas (intrinsic transaction cost), setting a new storage variable costs at least `21k + 20k = 41k` gas. In both cases a single 32 byte value is updated.

I think the reason updating balances costs less is the number of Patricia Trie nodes that need to be updated:

- for balance update at most 64 nodes (32 bytes for address, 2 nibbles each) has to be updated
- for storage slot update at most 128 nodes (32 bytes for the storage slot key + 32 bytes for the address - the account needs to be updated because its `storageRoot` would be changed).

There are on average 2 times more Patricia Trie nodes that has to be updated for storage slot write that's why it costs ~2 times more.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what i exactly wanted. It was really helpful.

Comment: I'm sorry but can u explain more detail about number of updating nodes? I've never heard about that exact number of nodes(64 and 128) to be updated. I thought all of nodes should be updated for balance or state change.

Comment: I meant the Patricia Trie nodes https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Patricia-Tree. All state including balances and contract storage is stored there. The maximum depth of the trie is 64 nodes because the keys are 32 bytes. For storage update, 2 tries need to be updated, that's why 128.